# Avoid re-instantiating Swift static computed property

Tags: swift, nscalendar

I have a class that needs a GMT calendar for many of its public functions. I simplified the functions this class performs for the sake of demonstration.

```
class GMTDate {
    private var date: Date

    init(dateInGMTDay date: Date) {
        self.date = GMTDate.gmtCal.startOfDay(for: date)
    }

    func daysInMonth() -> Int {
        return GMTDate.gmtCal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self.date)!.count
    }

    // Several other functions that use gmtCal

    private static var gmtCal: Int {
        var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        cal.timeZone = self.gmtTimeZone
        return cal
    }
}
```

The way I'm currently doing this, a new `Calendar` will be created every time a function is called on an instance of `GMTDate`. This is undesirable since if these functions are called many times, they will multiply the amount of time it takes for these functions to run by the instantiation time for `Calendar`. I'd prefer to have an instance already created an in memory, waiting to be used.

Another option would be to make `gmtCal` a lazily instantiated variable, and store a copy of an instantiated. Like this:

```
private var _gmtCal: Calendar?

private var gmtCal: Calendar {
    if let cal = _gmtCal {
        return cal
    }
    var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    cal.timeZone = GMTDate.gmtTimeZone
    _gmtCal = cal
    return cal
}
```

However, this would require storing a full `Calendar` with every `GMTDate`, which I'd prefer not to do since I may be creating lots of `GMTDate`s and I'd prefer not to increase the memory footprint of each `GMTDate` by the size of `Calendar`.

Is there another option? I'd like to only instantiate one copy of `Calendar` for use with this class, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although you can't lazily instantiate a lazy static variable with `private static lazy`, you can instantiate it manually as follows:

```
private static var _gmtCal: Calendar?
private static var gmtCal: Calendar {
    if let cal = GMTDate._gmtCal {
        return cal
    }
    var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    cal.timeZone = GMTDate.gmtTimeZone
    GMTDate._gmtCal = cal
    return cal
}
```